# Append domain name to email for editorFor

Tags: c#, javascript, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I am using C#, MVC4 to build an account class that has a property called GmailAccount, which will be entered by the user.

In Model, I am using the following RegularExpression attribute:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@gmail.com"]
```

This validates the email ends in `@gmail.com`.

In my html view, I am simply using:

```
 editorFor(model => model.GmailAccount) @@gmail.com
```

Note that I have typed in @@gmail in the html to save the user from typing in the domain name, and to ensure/enforce that user uses a valid gmail account.

However, we also note that the same RegularExpression attribute is validated on both the client and the server side. I really don't want my user to type in the domain name manually since I won't allow it to be different from "@gmail.com".

Question:

Is there a way to append @gmail.com to whatever the user provided in editorFor as the user name before both client side and server side validation? Or some other good alternatives?

Comment: Remove `@gmail.com` from the regex?

Comment: Adding `@gmail.com` to an input box is poor design from a user experience point of view.  If the value cannot change, don't provide the user with a way of editing it.  Instead make it [visually understandable what you are asking for](http://jsfiddle.net/U8xAg/) in the html itself (that example uses bootstrap).

Comment: Your question is very lacking in code, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: just add your domain constant '@gmail.com' in the setter for your property with the regex attribute.  Would be best if you would expose the constant through your model as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a view model around what you are trying to do:

```
public EmailEntryViewModel
{
  private string _emailPrefix = string.Empty;

  public string FullEmailAddress
  {
    get
    {
      return _emailPrefix + "@gmail.com";
    }
    set
    {
      if (!value.EndsWith("@gmail.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        //whatever logic that is internal
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Database contains an invalid email.");
      }

      this._emailPrefix = value.Substring(0,
        email.IndexOf("@gmail.com",  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
  }

 [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"]
  public string EmailPrefix
  {
    get 
    {
      return _emailPrefix;
    } 
    set 
    {
      _emailPrefix = value;
    } 
  }
}
```

Then you only need to:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailPrefix) @@gmail.com
```

Comment: Not quite correct.  The augmented regex you created would allow for any suffix - resulting in erroneous behavior according to the original post.

Comment: I'm not a regex expert by any means, this answers more of the `Is there a way to append @gmail.com to whatever the user provided in editorFor as the user name before both client side and server side validation? Or some other good alternatives?` and less about the correct way to do regex validation.